# WPF Text of Textbox in Grid during run-time is always empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm writing a C# WPF Desktop application.
For one window I get XAML-data from a database, which is a serialized Grid with labels and textboxes.
This deserializing works great. I see the labels and textboxes.

After typing in text in the textboxes I press a button.
I now need to know what I typed in. So I pass my grid (which has a name) and I loop through the children of the grid. I get the textboxes but their text is empty or has the value of the original XAML.
Nothing I've typed in is preserved.
The textboxes have no binding.

```
<Grid Name="GridQuestions">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="foo: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <TextBox Tag="CliFoo" Text="Test" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360" />

    <Label Content="Bar: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <TextBox Tag="CliBar" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360" />

    <Label Content="BlaBla: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <TextBox Tag="CliBlaBla" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360" />

</Grid>
```

In the button click I do:

```
foreach (var textbox in gridQuestions.Children.OfType<TextBox>().Where(textbox => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Tag.ToString())))
{
  DoSomething(textbox.Text);
}
```

For the 3 textboxes textbox.Text is always empty except for the first one which is 'test'.
But I don't get the values I typed in.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I use the technique explained in this post: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/82990/XAML-Serialization to (de-)serialize the XAML from the database.

This is the actual code I use:

```
var grid = (Grid)XamlReader.Parse(this.db.GridXaml);
this.QuestionsStackPanel.Children.Clear();
this.QuestionsStackPanel.Children.Add(grid);
```

As you can see I add it to a pre-existing stack panel.

Comment: Most certainly the deserialized Grid instance is not assigned to the `gridQuestions` field. You are operating on another instance.

Comment: Is the XAML that you posted generated by your deserialization process? How are you adding this XAML to the visual tree of your view?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've updated my question with the requested info. @Clemens: How can I check if I'm working with the same instance?

Comment: You could simply assign the Grid that is returned from XamlReader.Parse to the `gridQuestions` field: `gridQuestions = (Grid)XamlReader.Parse(...);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It is a combination of the comments and some more research.
First I changed from Name to x:Name in the XAML.
Next I added the grid like in my post. The suggestion of Clemens to use `gridQuestions = (Grid)XamlReader.Parse(...);` didn't work for me.

The last and most important part is like Clemens suggested, I was not operating on the correct instance.

Instead of using the name of the grid I'm now getting the first grid from the stackpanel: `var grid = this.QuestionsStackPanel.Children.OfType<Grid>().FirstOrDefault();`

Now I can read the values of the textboxes and can I move on.

Thanks again for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you declare "GridQuestions" in the XAML using Name, and not xName. You cannot use controls declared with Name only in the code behind.

Second, I would not recommend populating like that the TextBoxes. Better use binding, or if you have dynamically added text boxes, think about DataTemplates, and some sort of ListView or GridView.

Read about MVVM pattern [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx)